# How should it be handled when editing a question with extra code

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

While trying to format large blocks of code I often find extra code at the end of a code block. This could mean the user just cut too much code or is missing some code.  How should this be handled when editing?

Very Small Example:

```
public void foo(){
    string blah = "bar";
}
}
});
```

Would the proper thing to be to leave the extra }}) or remove them?

Comment: Don't touch it. Just leave a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The golden rule when it comes to code in questions is this:

> ***Do not even touch it with a 10 feet pole!***

The correct way would be to leave a comment and request clarification from the OP. Silently fixing code in questions can lead to one of three things:

1. You, by accident, removed the problem.
2. You, by accident, fixed the problem.
3. Nobody cares.

The first two are not desirable as they would render the question pretty much...broken.